# Reason for Error Timeout in CouchDB

Tags: ios, couchdb

I'm using CouchDB for my iOS application.

Following is my Application flow,

1. When my application is launched for the first time it replicates the remote database using xyz:a...@mmm.iriscouch.com/databasename.
2. if the replication is successful, everything works as expected, but sometimes the replication is not successful. In that case I'm getting the following error with log

   ```
    1> OTHER: {'EXIT',{error,timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.506>}}
   ```

   and it doesn't replicate until i remove the application and freshly reinstall the application on the device/simulator.
   is there any callback/delegate to handle this?

   - Somehow when I try synching with empty DB then I never get Error time out, once I have content in DB I get the error!

     Also it is hard to replicate on simulator, whereas on iPad occurrence is 90%.
3. i have placed the sample project in git hub 
   https://github.com/interactiveblueprints/CouchDBSyncTest (for couchDB username password,  please read readme.txt)

   - this sample code is just modification of PhotoLocations. An example application (https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iOS-Demo-PhotoLocations), But changed as per my requirement.
4. I have also attached the error logs in 
   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35814355/ErrorLog.rtf

Waiting for reply,
Krishna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with your sample and updated the "Couchbase.framework" to the latest one, from https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchCocoa and now the problem seems to be solved, may be this was a bug in previous version. now it seems the DB tries to restart by itself. and the replication feels more smoother and faster.